# I want to search on OMalley name in sql and it should bring back values with wildcard like O'Malley

Tags: sql

I want to search on  OMalley name in sql or linq and it should bring back values with wildcard like  O'Malley or O_Malley is it possible??

Comment: `where name like 'O%Malley'`, or `where name like 'O_Malley'`.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am implementing a  dynamic search function in .net. So in application user can enter any name - like smith or Omalley but if in the database if they stored with wildcard it should bring those values too.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your where clause:

```
where name like "O%M%"
```